# Get data from in compile time C#

Tags: c#, compilation

I've been trying to write C# code that retrieves data from a file in compilation-time, and not in run-time.
The thing is that I need to get a version of a file that exists in my machine,
but not in machines that would run this DLL. (The version can be changed tomorrow, so I want to able to retrieve that dynamically). 
In run-time, those machines have no access to the file, and that's why I need to get this data before.
Anyone as an idea how to do so ?
Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want a resource embedded in your DLL.

Answer (score 2):

The C# code that you are compiling will not be run during the compilation.

You should make a pre-build step that extracts the version information. That custom build step could in itself be a C# program if you want. Make that program output a small .cs file containing the version number of the dll and include that .cs file in the source for the main program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something before or after a project is built you can write a command line statement in `pre-build event command line` or in `post-build command line` in `Build Events` section of project properties.